# Better command line interface

Tags: c, xml, command-line-interface

I have developed a application which caches multiple packages. The CLI interface for this application is as follows

```
submit -z pkg1.zip -c pkgChecksum1 -t pkgType1 -s pkgSize1 -z pkg2.zip -c pkgChecksum2 -t pkgType2 -s pkgSize2
```

So this submits 2 packages pkg1.zip and pkg2.zip which have checksum pkgChecksum1 and pkgChecksum2 respectively, package type as pkgType1 and pkgType2, and size as pkgSize1 and pkgSize2 respectively.

We also provide XML Based input to the application which is as follows

```
submit --script an.xml
```

where an.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<packages>
<package name="pkg1.zip" checksum="pkgChecksum1" type="pkgType1" size="pkgSize1" />
<package name="pkg2.zip" checksum="pkgChecksum2" type="pkgType2" size="pkgSize2" />
</packages>
```

This is the functional equivalent of the first CLI method.

We were planning to make this more user friendly, any ideas to improve?

Comment: Why do you have an unclosed `<xml>` tag in your XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are all the options required?  Or are there defaults for type and size and checksum?
If there are no defaults, you could get rid of the tags and just require arguments in groups of four.

```
submit pkg1.zip pkg1Cksum pkg1type pkg1sz pkg2.zip pkg2Cksum pkg2type pkg2sz
```

Another option in this case is to use the tags, but prompt the user for missing values.

If there are defaults (can the checksum and size be calculated automatically?), allow seletive overrides:

```
submit pkg1.zip -t pkg1type pkg2.zip -t pkg2type -s pkg2szOverride
```

Another option that might be helpful is a `-a existingCache`, which appends to an existing file (or creates it if not present).  This would let the user break it up into several 
maneagable command lines

```
   submit -a mycache pkg1.zip -t pkg1type -s pkg1sz
   submit -a mycache pkg2.zip -t pkg2type -s pkg2sz
```

One more option, based on the comments:

```
  submit -x pkg1.zip:2034 0x232D -y pkg2.zip pkg3.zip:123
```

where -x,-y, etc are flags for the different supported "types".  So this line submits pkg1 with size 2034, type X, and a checksum; pkg2 of type y, no size or checksum specified; and pkg3 of size 123 with no type or checksum specified.

Comment: checksum, type and size are not required. No defaults. 
There is no ordering for arguments. Hence the user could provide first the package name, size, type and then checksum as well. That is why we keep the tags to identify them.

Comment: at the very least, I'd not require the -z on the package names, since they are required.

Comment: Is the checksum a file containing the checksum, or a string like 0x1ab2?  Are the allowable types a restricted set?

Comment: checksum is a crc32 hash like the one you mentioned 0x1ab2.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide long options along with short option for the various parameters in the CLI.
For example

```
submit --package pkg1.zip --checksum pkgChecksum1 --type pkgType1 --size pkgSize1 --package  pkg2.zip -checksum pkgChecksum2 --type pkgType2 --size pkgSize2
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you should do. It depends on who is the target audience of your application. Two possible options:

1. GUI interface, for users that don't know / are scared of using CLI
2. Interactive CLI, similar to this:

> ```
> Package name:
> > pkg1.zip
> Checksum:
> > pkgChecksum1
> Type:
> pkgType1
> ```

Comment: The application is used by Power Users, who really prefer CLI :). Interactive CLI is difficult to automate.

Comment: That's why interactive CLI is a bad choice if it is the only interface. But if you already have other interfaces, that are easy to automate, adding interactive CLI *could* be a good idea.

Comment: We currently have only 1. But I like your idea of having separate interfaces for automation and human input. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another option that occurs to me:

```
submit pkg1.zip:type:2034:0x232D     pkg2.zip:type2:2034:0x232D
```

I think that the problem is that submit can manage multiple options for each parameter, so adding each of them at once could make the interface simpler. Remebering type, size and chksum for each one should not be difficult. After all, it seems that all parameters are mandatory. This way, it is not possible to mess the options for one package with the options for the other one.